# Mousein on picture

Tags: css

how to install it when you walk across the image change the mouse cursor to be my heart this picture while I was in the picture ?
thank you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iUO7.png)

Comment: You may want to do some research on 'How to change cursor by javascript'

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: this arrow ( heart) to appear before you cross the image below . I do not know whether I have phrased the question ?!

Comment: Please go into more detail about what you need, and what you have tried and try and provide some code examples.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand, you want when you hover over the image, the default cursor to change to a heart.

so use this , and instead of the stackoverflow favicon.ico use your heart image

```css
img {
  cursor:url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico), auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
```